# Redirect when translation of node is unavailable

Tags: i18n-l10n, redirection

I have installed pathauto and i18n and I would like to create a node which is only available in one language. Lets say I have a Basic Page with the URL:

www.example.de/test-page-in-german

so I dont want this page to be available from

www.example.pl/test-page-in-german

because I am afraid google is gonna ban my site for double content.
Ive already selected "Require language (Do not allow Language Neutral)" for my content type and for "test-page-in-german" I have selected german and their is no translation but the node is still visible from other language domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) Module

I had to enable the option ***Language Path Checking***.

Then I got another problem with the redirects which was fixed by this patch:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1514166#comment-11657665